# Replace Button with horizontal line in javascript, Html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using one input button for hide and show image div and Using html5, jquery, Css3. But right now i want to replace button with one horizontal line. Whenever move point in line then button is triggered.

Right now i have normal button, I am showing in below image:[image]

But i want one line replace of this button like below image[image]

I am using three image div and after click on rotate but it is showing next image div.

switchVisible() is a function for show and hide of image.
 I don't have
 any about this please give me some idea.

I am using this button code:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Rotate" onclick="switchVisible();"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean `$("#Button1").replaceWith($("<hr />"))`?

Comment: Just post what you have so far, including your JS code

Comment: I guess range input can do what you want. `<input type="range" onchange ="switchVisible();" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use j[query.ui slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) for your line to switch between images.

something like this:

```
$("#imageLine").slider({
    value: 0,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        //you can detect where ui.slider stops here
        console.log(ui.value)

        //and run your function then
        switchVisible(ui.value);
    }
});

function switchVisible(){
     ...your logic for displaying images depending on ui.slider position
}
```